# Angularjs model change only in view, not in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

probably a newbie question.

I have a problem where my databinding in the HTML updates just fine, but the log_interval function always console log "3". I want to use the updated model "interval" to send a request to a timeseries database, with different intervals. But every time I'm sending just 3, even though my view is updating as it should.

I've tried with $scope.$watch (like in the snippet), but it only triggers when the page is loading.
Also I tried with ng-change and ng-click, both in all the radio buttons respectively and in the  element. I tried to call $scope.$watch, but I get an error saying $digest is already running. Nothing works :(
How can I update my model in the controller, so that I can use it for different HTTP request?

```js
.controller('DashCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log) {

  $scope.interval = 3;

  $scope.$watch("interval", function() {
    $log.log($scope.interval);
  }, true);
  
  $scope.log_interval = function() {
    $log.log($scope.interval);
  };
 
}])

;
```

```html
<h1>{{interval}}</h1>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="interval" btn-radio="1" uncheckable>1 day</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="interval" btn-radio="2" uncheckable>3 days</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="interval" btn-radio="3" uncheckable>1 week</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="interval" btn-radio="4" uncheckable>2 weeks</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="interval" btn-radio="5" uncheckable>1 month</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="interval" btn-radio="6" uncheckable>3 months</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: I do not think you have established a proper two-way databinding.  Otherwise, you would not want to update model to reflect the view. It happens by itself. And, I do not get what you are trying to do in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work fine.

I noticed you seem to be using the UI-Bootstrap, so I forked their Plunkr showing how to do this in their [documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

See the working Plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7KrUqA7BAE0eZFUXMp5D?p=preview), which uses your code.

HTML:

```
<h4>Radio &amp; Uncheckable Radio</h4>
<pre>{{interval || 'null'}}</pre>
<div class="btn-group">
  <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="interval" btn-radio="1" uncheckable>1 day</label>
  <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="interval" btn-radio="2" uncheckable>3 days</label>
  <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="interval" btn-radio="3" uncheckable>1 week</label>
  <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="interval" btn-radio="4" uncheckable>2 weeks</label>
  <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="interval" btn-radio="5" uncheckable>1 month</label>
  <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="interval" btn-radio="6" uncheckable>3 months</label>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.interval = 3;

$scope.$watch("interval", function() {
  console.log($scope.interval);
}, true);
```

To be clear, this `$scope.interval` value updates *automatically* when you select the button. So you do not have to update anything manually (which is one of the major benefits of using Angular). So whenever you need to do the HTTP request, just access the `$scope.interval` value and it will be the correct value.

In other words: you do not need the `$scope.$watch` unless there is more complicated logic you need to do whenever the selected button changes

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time to answer! I understand that $watch should be kind of unnecessary here, but it was an attempt to force the updated model, and then run the request from there (the change event). But for some reason, I don't get the console.log($scope.interval), like in the plunkr you provided. It prints out absolutely nothing. It's like the model is only changed in the HTML and not in the controller?

Comment: @user3430863 This could have something to do with your project setup. See if you can set it up more like the Plunkr. Make sure you have the correct ui-bootstrap javascript files included and you are injecting everything correctly

Comment: Are you binding your controller in the HTML using `ng-controller`? Is this your whole setup or is there more HTML code surrounding this?

Comment: Thank you all! Very nice of you to put such effort into my problem :) I figured could call the function with the model as a parameter, thus being sure it changes. I dont know however if this is the correct method, but it works! :)

 `<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" ng-click="request(interval)">`